# Working with Transpose functions result in error

Tags: arrays, ruby

consider the following array

```
arr = [["Locator", "Test1", "string1","string2","string3","string4"],
       ["$LogicalName", "Create Individual Contact","value1","value2"]]
```

Desired result:

```
[Test1=>{"string1"=>"value1","string2"=>"value2","string3"=>"","string4"=>""}]
```

When I do transpose, it gives me the error by saying second element of the array is not the length of the first element in the array,

```
Uncaught exception: element size differs (2 should be 4)
```

so is there any to add empty string in the place where there is no element and can perform the transpose and then create the hash as I have given above? The array may consist of many elements with different length but according to the size of the first element in the array, every other inner array has to change by inserting empty string and then I can do the transpose. Is there any way?

Comment: That data structure doesn't sound very suitable for `transpose`. You may get better answers by describing the result you want instead of a particular method you want to call.

Comment: @matthewd Hi check it out now.

Comment: Your desired result is not a Ruby object. Do you mean it to be a hash (rather than an array)? btw, note that in my editing of your question (which I did mainly to avoid the need for readers to scroll horizontally to read the code) I assigned a variable (`arr`) to the input array. You should do that routinely to allow readers to reference such nvariables in answers and comments without having to define them. Lastly, do we know `"Test1"` is to be the key, `arr[0][1]` is to be the key, or something else? Similar questions about about `"stringX"` and `"valueX"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might want `Enumerable#zip`:

```
headers, *data_rows = input_data
headers.zip(*data_rows)
# => [["Locator", "$LogicalName"], ["Test1", "Create Individual Contact"],
#     ["string1", "value1"], ["string2", "value2"], ["string3", nil], ["string4", nil]]
```

Comment: If you really need the blanks to be `""`, that's an easy `map` away... but I'd argue that `nil` is a more idiomatic choice of value to fill the gaps.

Comment: That's absolute what I want, But also I want one more adding, that's this `p  result[1..-1].map{|dataRow| result[0].zip(dataRow).to_h}`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to transpose an array of arrays, each element of the array must be the same size. Here you would need to do something like the following.

```
arr = [["Locator", "Test1", "string1","string2","string3","string4"],
       ["$LogicalName", "Create Individual Contact","value1","value2"]]

keys, vals = arr
  #=> [["Locator", "Test1", "string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"],
  #    ["$LogicalName", "Create Individual Contact", "value1", "value2"]]
idx = keys.index("Test1") + 1
  #=> 2

{ "Test1" => [keys[idx..-1],
              vals[idx..-1].
                concat(['']*(keys.size - vals.size))].
                transpose.
                to_h }
  #=> {"Test1"=>{"string1"=>"value1", "string2"=>"value2", "string3"=>"", "string4"=>""}}
```

It is not strictly necessary to define the variables `keys` and `vals`, but that avoids the need to create those arrays multiple times. It reads better as well, in my opinion.

The steps are as follows. Note `keys.size #=> 6` and `vals.size #=> 4`.

```
a = vals[idx..-1]
  #=> vals[2..-1]
  #=> ["value1", "value2"]
b = [""]*(keys.size - vals.size)
  #=> [""]*(4 - 2)
  #=> ["", ""]
c = a.concat(b)
  #=> ["value1", "value2", "", ""]
d = keys[idx..-1]
  #=> ["string1", "string2", "string3", "string4"]
e = [d, c].transpose
  #=> [["string1", "value1"], ["string2", "value2"], ["string3", ""], ["string4", ""]]
f = e.to_h
  #=> {"string1"=>"value1", "string2"=>"value2", "string3"=>"", "string4"=>""}
f = e.to_h
  #=> { "Test1" => f }
```

Comment: Excellent answer! Test1 should not be hard-coded but I will take it from array.

Answer (score 0):

Find the longest Element in your Array and make sure every other element has the same length - loop and add `maxLength - element(i).length` amount of "" elements.